# How do I install a LAMP stack?

Tags: web-development, software-installation

A LAMP stack consist of Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP. What is the best way to install this stack for local development?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

It installs the following:

```
apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-mpm-prefork libaio1 libapache2-mod-php5
libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libdbd-mysql-perl
libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient18 libterm-readkey-perl
mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
mysql-server-core-5.5 php5-cli php5-common php5-json php5-mysql php5-readline
```

As a summary, that includes `apache`, `mysql` and `php`.

Answer (score 2):

For development, you should use Bitnami.

It's a standalone server package that handles it's own versions of the tools you need. It also helps you keep your system clean from development related modifications.

[Get it here](https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xampp for Development LAMP environment. It will provide you manage LAMP with GUI. You can download it [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html).

Give execution permission to Xampp Installer file by using following command.

```
sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-x.x.xx-0-installer.run
```

Run the installer file:

```
./xampp-linux-x.x.xx-0-installer.run
```

GUI Installation windows will be open and you will have installed Xampp.